# div added with javascript not showing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a div using javascript. The div is appearing in the code and in chromes developer tools but not showing in the actual window ?

Why is this happening, how can I correct this ?

Code:

```
<div id='body'>
    <div id='inner'>div here</div>
</div>

<script>

function add() {
var inner = document.getElementById('inner');

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.height = '300px';
    div.style.width = '100px';
    div.style.color = 'blue';
    inner.appendChild(div);

}

add();



</script>
```

Comment: color is used for text, not for background. see http://jsfiddle.net/er779/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have set text `color`, not background-color. So it is there, it's just that it has no content so you can't see it. I assume you meant this:

```
div.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

Comment: Based on that this is the answer, I'd recommend the OP look at the DOM with an inspector tool to catch this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it's working for me.

you have to add **onload()** in body tag

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function add() {

var inner = document.getElementById('inner');
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "300px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "blue";


inner.appendChild(div);
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload ="add()">

<div id="inner"></div>

</body>
</html>
```